# NSJSONSerialization output number as float?

Tags: ios, cocoa, foundation, nsjsonserialization

I'm using `NSJSONSerialization` to convert a dictionary into JSON.

If I include an NSDecimalNumber ( == 0 ) in that dictionary it outputs as `0`. This is wrong. `0` is an int. I need it to output as `0.0`.

This is what I'm doing:

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.0f];
// when fed into NSJSONSerialization it outputs as 0
```

Is there any way to output as `0.0`?

OR am I incorrect in my assumption? Is `0` a valid float?

Comment: Although `0` is not considered a constant of type `float` in the Objective-C programming language, it is definitely a valid float number. Since JSON encodes things as name-value pairs, without type information, it's up to the receiving side to decide the final type of the deserialized field.

Comment: So what you want is that your JSON looks like this?:
{
 myFloat: 0.0
...}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to affect the way `NSJSONSerialization` outputs numbers. But you really should not worry about this. JSON doesn’t distinguish between different types of numbers, so you always should accept numbers with and without decimal points, no matter what the actual type of number you are doing your calculations with.